# How to get a specific parameter in an url and add that to another url in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Only learnt coding for 2 weeks so sorry for noob questions!

I am trying to build a chrome extension that runs the following when I click a button on popup.html:

1. gets and reads the urls of each tab one by one
2. if the url starts with "https://www.linkedin.com/company/", gets the company ID right after "company/". (The url usually looks like this: https://www.linkedin.com/company/164233?trk=prof-exp-company-name so in this case for example, I would like to get "164233") Then it should create a new tab with the following url: https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=164233

So far here are the codes I have for this button:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
    document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', loadSeeAllEmployees);
});

function loadSeeAllEmployees(e){
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true, 'currentWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    for (i=0; i<chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow().length; i++){
        if(tabs.url.indexOf("https://www.linkedin.com/company/")){

        }
    }
};

}
```

So the name of the button is 'btn2' and the function is 'loadSeeAllEmployees'

I am stuck here because I don't know how to get that specific parameter and how I can add it to another url.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### String.prototype.slice()

#### [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

The slice method extracts a section of a string and returns a new string.

---

If I am not misunderstanding the question, using the slice function will get what you need, assuming the URL format is consistent.

This probably isn't the most reliable method, but:

```
var query = tabs[0].url;
var companyId = query.slice(32, 38);
```

Comment: thanks! But sometimes the company ID is more than 5 numbers

Comment: var companyId = query.replace( /^\D+/g, ''); //replaces all nonnumbers with nothing. I pulled it from another question, but it should work if the url contains no other numbers. I it does, you can slice it up to 32 or whatever and then until whatever the maximum length for a company id would be